# Comment multiple lines in a file using sed

Tags: shell, sed

I am working on MAC OSX. I am writing shell script to add prefix "//" to all the log messages in a file. I wrote the following sed script:

```
    sed -i '' "s|"log+*"|"//log"|g" filename
```

The script is working fine when the log message has single line. But if the log has multiple lines it fails. eg:

```
    log("hi
         how are
         you");
```

the output for this comes out to be :

```
    //log("hi
           how are
           you");
```

But, I want the output to be:

```
    //log("hi
    //     how are
    //     you");
```

Since I haven't used sed much I don't know how to do this. So, Is it possible to do this using sed. If yes how?

Thanks

Comment: Are you limited in using `sed` or is some other tools like `awk` available?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R  Currently I am using sed, But if this can be done using any other tool I can use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest method is to use address ranges

```
sed "/^\s*log.*;$/ s|^|//|; /^\s*log/, /);$/ s|^|//|" input
```

**What it does?**

- `/^\s*log.*;$/ s|^|//|` If the line starts with `log` and ends with `;` then substitute the start, `^` with `//`
- `/\s*^log/, /);$/ s|^|//|"`

  - `/^log/, /);$/` This is an address range. For all lines within this range, the substitution is performed. The range of lines start from the first regex match to the end match.

**Test**

```
$ cat input
log("hi
         how are
         you");

this will also be not commented; 

log ("test);

this is not commented;

$  sed "/^\s*log.*;$/ s|^|//|; /^\s*log/, /);$/ s|^|//|" input
//log("hi
//         how are
//         you");

this will also be not commented; 

//log ("test);

this is not commented;
```

Comment: Depending on indentation of the log commands, `/^\s*log.../` for each of the pattern matches might prove a useful tweak.

Comment: @cmbuckley That makes it more perfects. Thank you for the tip. Updated in answer :)

Comment: @nu11p01n73R I tried your suggestion, but it still doesn't seems to work if there are some spaces prefixed to the line.Is it working at your end ?

Comment: For MAC OS we need to use [[sapce]] to match spaces.
sed "/^[[:space:]]*log.*;$/ s|^|//|; /^[[:space:]]*log/, /);$/ s|^|//|"  works on Mac OS. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed '/log/{:a;s/.*/\\\\\0/;/);[[:space:]]*$/!{n;ba}}' input.txt
```

- `/log(/` searches for a line containing the openeing term `log(`.
- `{` opens a block of code
- `:a` defines a lable called `a`
- `s/.*/\\\\\0/` adds `\\` in front of the line
- `/);[[:space:]]*$` searches for the closing `);` followed by optional spaces at the end of the line
- `!{n;ba}` gets executed if the pattern was not found. `n` gets a new line. `ba` branches back to `a`.

Comment: It is giving an error saying: sed: 1: "/log/{:a;s/.*/\\\\\0/;/ ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s) .

Comment: Make sure you copy pasted the command correctly. It *is* working.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it cannot work. You're performing sed on the word "log", which means that if this word is not present at the beginning of each line, you won't replace anything.

Can you confirm it does work if you add the "log" word at the beginning of the first three lines ?

If yes, the solution would be to keep the same command but to remove the word "log". Maybe something like `sed -i '' "s|"+*"|"//"|g" filename` (I'm not familiar with sed for Mac OS X so I won't make any statement here).